# How do you recreate this function in Python pandas from R? Group by and then unique

Tags: python, r, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i.

The function in R:

```
dataframe %>% group_by(a, b, c) %>% select(-g, -h, -i) %>% unique() %>% ungroup()
```

I tried:

```
dataframe.drop_duplicates(dataframe.columns.difference(["g", "h", "i"]))
```

but it gives fewer rows than the R code.

However, it gives the same number of rows as:

```
dataframe %>% group_by(a, b, c, d, e, f) %>% select(-g, -h, -i) %>% unique() %>% ungroup()
```

What's the difference between these two functions and how can I recreate it?

Comment: can you post example data and desired output?

Comment: You can dump your data using `dput` as in `dput(dataframe)`.

Comment: To simplify your R version, you can just drop columns g, h, and i before grouping. You can also do the same in pandas. At that point it should be just doing the correct group by in pandas. I think in your pandas code, you are dropping duplicates without doing the `group_by`